# Insert HTML using Writer.insert* functions in CKEditor 5

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I see that `Writer` class has methods to insert Text. However, I fail to understand as to which of those methods is the right one to insert HTML into the editor.

#### Explanations

My case scenario is:
 A User can create certain content template and save it. Later the user should be able to insert that same content into the editor and start modifying.

I'm handling this using the following code

```
activeCKE.model.change( writer => {
    writer.insertElement( "text to insert", activeCKE.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition() );
    activeCKE.setData(activeCKE.getData()); // to refresh the contents

}
```

It works well with "**text**" but not with " `<strong>text</strong>`". The latter appears as-is.

So my question is; **What is the right way to insert the HTML string programatically that has already been created using something like the `Writer` class?**

I see there is a concept of template in `ui/template`, however I'm unclear as how to convert `editor.getData()` to that template.

**Please Note:** I don't want to give the user an HTML editing interface. I just want to create templates to make his life easier. Hence my question has nothing to do with 'View Source Code' based questions.

Answer (score 5):

While I continued my research post asking this question, I landed onto FAQs, where I got my answer.

```
const viewFragment = activeCKE.data.processor.toView( "<p>HTML Text</p>" );
const modelFragment = activeCKE.data.toModel( viewFragment );

activeCKE.model.insertContent( modelFragment, activeCKE.model.document.selection );
```

This satisfies my use case. However, I encourage the community to post other possible variations, such as using `Template` class. **Especially because line-breaks due to any kind of tag (br, p etc) are filtered out.**

Developers interested to show the source code & allow source code manipulation in **CKEditor 5**, can create a plugin that shows the contents of `editor.getData()` in a dialog (or something they like) and then reset the contents of editor and insert the content in a fashion similar to the one demonstrated above.